# How to enable google places API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating an app that uses **google maps API** and then displays the address of the user's location gained from the places API on top, however when I try to access the places API I get the below mentioned error:

> "com.example.android.rsrpechhulp3 E/Volley: [584] fc.a: Unexpected
>   response code 400 for https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api"

followed by a

> "FATAL EXCEPTION: main"

at the first line I use the places API

I have API keys for both `google maps SDK` and `google places SDK`, and have put google places SDK as an API restriction of google maps SDK. 
the manifest contains:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

I know that the google maps API key is correct as the google maps functioned correctly before i tried to implement code using places.